# Recreating a diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to recreate the following diagrams with TikZ
[image]

with the help of answers for different questions on this site and the pgfmanual here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every pin edge/.style={black,thin}, pin distance=7mm]
    \begin{axis}[ 
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis lines =middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
          ]

       \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3,-2,...,2,3}{
         \ifnum #1 = -2
           \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^2*#1} coordinate[pos=0.68] (n#1);
         \else
           \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2:2] {x^2*#1} coordinate[pos=0.64-0.02*#1] (n#1);
         \fi
         \node[inner sep=1pt,pin={[anchor=west]30:$y=#1x^2$}] at (n#1) {};
        }

\addplot [blue,domain=0:360,dashed] ({.5*cos(x)},{.5*sin(x)});
\addplot [blue,domain=0:360,dashed] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)});
\addplot [blue,domain=0:360,dashed] ({1.5*cos(x)},{1.5*sin(x)});
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
        decoration = {brace,
        amplitude=6pt}]

\tikzset{arrowheads/.style={<->, >=stealth}}
\tikzset{ind arrow/.style={->, blue, bend left=-30, opacity=0.4}}


\draw [->] (-4,0) -- (3.5,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-4) -- (0,3.5) node [above] {$y$};
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (1.7cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);

\draw [dashed,color=blue,domain = -1.7:1.8] plot(\x, {-1*\x});
\draw [dashed,color=blue,domain = -1.7:1.8] plot(\x, {1*\x});
\draw [dashed,color=blue,domain = -1.7:1.8] plot(\x, {2*\x});

\draw [color=blue, fill=blue] (.8,.6) circle (0pt) node (T){};
\node (Q)[above=.5in,right of=T]{};
\node (R)[right of=Q]{};
\node (P) [blue, above right of=R, align=center] {};

\draw [ind arrow, out=-30, in=180] (P.south east) node[right] {$x^2+\frac12y^2=1$} to (T);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any refinement is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks reminiscent of your screen shots. It assumes that you want to draw the ellipses as plots, not just as ellipses, the second one draws the circles as circles, not as plot. I use `axis equal` and a parametrization that fits the description. (I also improved the formulae according to minhthien_2016's suggestion).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=10cm,}
\tikzset{connect with angle/.style={to path={%
let \p1=(\tikztostart),\p2=(\tikztotarget),
\n1={sin(#1-atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1))} in 
-- ++({(\y2-\y1)*cot(#1)},{\y2-\y1}) -- (\tikztotarget)
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal,clip=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,
            axis lines =middle, xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west}
          ]

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-3,-2,...,2,3}{
     \ifnum #1 = 0
       \addplot [blue, smooth,domain=-2.5:2.5] {#1*x^2} coordinate[pos={0.2}] (n#1);
     \else
       \addplot [blue, smooth,domain={-sqrt(2.5/abs(#1))}:{sqrt(2.5/abs(#1))}] {#1*x^2} 
       coordinate[pos=0.45-0.12*abs(#1)] (n#1);
     \node[inner sep=1pt,anchor=east,] (nn#1) at ([xshift=1cm]current axis.west|-n#1) 
     {$y=\ifnum#1=1
     \else 
     \ifnum#1=-1
     -\else
     #1
     \fi\fi x^2$};
     \draw[-latex,thin] (nn#1) -- (n#1);
     \fi
    }
   \addplot [blue,domain=0:360,dashed] ({.5*sqrt(2)*cos(x)},{.5*sin(x)})
   coordinate[pos=0.95] (e0);
   \addplot [blue,domain=0:360,dashed] ({sqrt(2)*cos(x)},{sin(x)})
   coordinate[pos=0.05] (e1);
   \addplot [blue,domain=0:360,dashed] ({1.5*sqrt(2)*cos(x)},{1.5*sin(x)})
   coordinate[pos=0.1] (e2);
   \path ([yshift=-2mm]current axis.east|-e0)  node (ne0) {$y^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2=0.5$}
   ([yshift=2mm]e1-|current axis.east)  node  (ne1){$y^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2=1$}
   ([yshift=2mm]e2-|current axis.east)  node  (ne2) {$y^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2=1.5$};
 \end{axis}
   \foreach \X in {0,1,2}
   {\draw[latex-,thin] (e\X) to[connect with angle={-10+30*sign(\X)}]  (ne\X.west);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [-stealth] (-4,0) -- (3.5,0) node [right] {$x$};
  \draw [-stealth] (0,-4) -- (0,3.5) node [above] {$y$};
  \foreach \X in {1,2,4}
  {\draw (0,0) circle[radius={sqrt(\X)*1cm}] (10:{sqrt(\X)})coordinate (c\X);}
  \draw [dashed,blue] (-3.5,-3.5) -- (3.5,3.5) coordinate[pos=0.9] (x2)
   (-3.5,3.5) -- (3.5,-3.5) coordinate[pos=0.05] (x1)
   (-4/2,-4) -- (4/2,4) coordinate[pos=0.95] (x3);
  \draw[latex-,thin] (x1) -- ++ (-0.5,0) node[left]{$y=-x$};
  \draw[latex-,thin] (x2) -- ++ (0.5,0) node[right]{$y=x$};
  \draw[latex-,thin] (x3) -- ++ (0.5,0) node[right]{$y=2x$};
  \path (4,0.6) node[right] (r4) {$y^2+x^2=4$};
  \path (4,1.2) node[right] (r2){$y^2+x^2=2$};
  \path (4,1.8) node[right] (r1) {$y^2+x^2=1$};
     \foreach \X in {1,2,4}
     {\draw[latex-,thin] (c\X) to[connect with angle={40-\X*5}]  (r\X.west);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of writting `1x^2`, we write `x^2`?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Yes, you're right. I corrected it.

Comment: 1x^2 is super cool though.